# Python - UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1070: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to run a regex on some files in bulk.

> the regex code:

```
import re


def DOCtoSTRING(path):

   return text

def valuesHextractor(text):
   STRING =""
   #let's find pacient personal info
   regex = re.compile('CONSULTAŢIE(?s).*EXAMENUL')
   pacientdata=regex.search(text)
   pacientinfo = re.sub('[A-Z]+:',"",pacientdata[0])
   STRING=STRING+pacientinfo.strip("CONSULTAŢIE").strip("EXAMENUL")+" "

   #values
   regex = re.compile('EXAMENUL OFTALMOLOGIC:(?s).*TRATAMENT')
   pacientvalues=regex.search(text)

   #AV OD
   #fc
   regex=re.compile("1.AV.*OD.*?fc[;\.\+\- 0-9]*")
   AVfc=regex.search(pacientvalues[0])
   AVODfc=re.sub("1.AV.*OD.*?fc[;\. 0-9]*?","",AVfc[0])
   regex=re.compile("[\+\-0-9]+")
   if regex.search(AVODfc)==None:
       AVODfc="None"
   STRING=STRING+AVODfc+" "
   #cc
   regex=re.compile("1.AV.*OD.*?cc[;\.\+\- 0-9]*")
   AVcc=regex.search(pacientvalues[0])
   AVODcc=re.sub("1.AV.*OD.*?cc[;\. 0-9]*?","",AVcc[0])
   regex=re.compile("[\+\-0-9]+")
   if regex.search(AVODcc)==None:
       AVODcc="None"
   STRING=STRING+AVODcc+" "
   #cyl
   regex=re.compile("1.AV.*OD.*?cyl[;\.\+\- 0-9]*")
   AVcyl=regex.search(pacientvalues[0])
   AVODcyl=re.sub("1.AV.*OD.*?cyl[;\. 0-9]*?","",AVcyl[0])
   regex=re.compile("[\+\-0-9]+")
   if regex.search(AVODcyl)==None:
       AVODcyl="None"
   STRING=STRING+AVODcyl+" "
   #ax
   regex=re.compile("1.AV.*OD.*?ax[;\.\+\- 0-9]*")
   AVax=regex.search(pacientvalues[0])
   AVODax=re.sub("1.AV.*OD.*?ax[;\. 0-9]*?","",AVax[0])
   regex=re.compile("[\+\-0-9]+")
   if regex.search(AVODax)==None:
       AVODax="None"
   STRING=STRING+AVODax+" "

   #AV OS
   #fc
   regex=re.compile("1.AV.*OS.*?fc[;\. 0-9]*")
   AVfc=regex.search(pacientvalues[0])
   AVOSfc=re.sub("1.AV.*OS.*?fc[;\. 0-9]*?","",AVfc[0])
   regex=re.compile("[\+\-0-9]+")
   if regex.search(AVOSfc)==None:
       AVOSfc="None"
   STRING=STRING+AVOSfc+" "
   #cc
   regex=re.compile("1.AV.*OS.*?cc[;\.\+\- 0-9]*")
   AVcc=regex.search(pacientvalues[0])
   AVOScc=re.sub("1.AV.*OS.*?cc[;\. 0-9]*?","",AVcc[0])
   regex=re.compile("[\+\-0-9]+")
   if regex.search(AVOScc)==None:
       AVOScc="None"
   STRING=STRING+AVOScc+" "
   #cyl
   regex=re.compile("1.AV.*OS.*?cyl[;\.\+\- 0-9]*")
   AVcyl=regex.search(pacientvalues[0])
   AVOScyl=re.sub("1.AV.*OS.*?cyl[;\. 0-9]*?","",AVcyl[0])
   regex=re.compile("[\+\-0-9]+")
   if regex.search(AVOScyl)==None:
       AVOScyl="None"
   STRING=STRING+AVOScyl+" "
   #ax
   regex=re.compile("1.AV.*OS.*?ax[;\.\+\- 0-9]*")
   AVax=regex.search(pacientvalues[0])
   AVOSax=re.sub("1.AV.*OS.*?ax[;\. 0-9]*?","",AVax[0])
   regex=re.compile("[\+\-0-9]+")
   if regex.search(AVOSax)==None:
       AVOSax="None"
   STRING=STRING+AVOSax+" "


############From here ignore names check only the #name

####### DP
   regex=re.compile("1.AV.*OS.*?DP=[;\.\+\- 0-9]*")
   AVax=regex.search(pacientvalues[0])
   AVOSax=re.sub("1.AV.*OS.*?DP=[;\. 0-9]*?","",AVax[0])
   regex=re.compile("[\+\-0-9]+")
   if regex.search(AVOSax)==None:
       AVOSax="None"
   DP=AVOSax

##########

   #RO OD
   #cyl
   regex=re.compile("2.RO.*OD.*?cyl[;\.\+\- 0-9]*")
   AVcyl=regex.search(pacientvalues[0])
   AVODcyl=re.sub("2.RO.*OD.*?cyl[;\. 0-9]*?","",AVcyl[0])
   regex=re.compile("[\+\-0-9]+")
   if regex.search(AVODcyl)==None:
       AVODcyl="None"
   STRING=STRING+AVODcyl+" "
   #ax
   regex=re.compile("2.RO.*OD.*?ax[;\.\+\- 0-9]*")
   AVax=regex.search(pacientvalues[0])
   AVODax=re.sub("2.RO.*OD.*?ax[;\. 0-9]*?","",AVax[0])
   regex=re.compile("[\+\-0-9]+")
   if regex.search(AVODax)==None:
       AVODax="None"
   STRING=STRING+AVODax+" "


   #RO OS
   #cyl
   regex=re.compile("2.RO.*OS.*?cyl[;\.\+\- 0-9]*")
   AVcyl=regex.search(pacientvalues[0])
   AVOScyl=re.sub("2.RO.*OS.*?cyl[;\. 0-9]*?","",AVcyl[0])
   regex=re.compile("[\+\-0-9]+")
   if regex.search(AVOScyl)==None:
       AVOScyl="None"
   STRING=STRING+AVOScyl+" "
   #ax
   regex=re.compile("2.RO.*OS.*?ax[;\.\+\- 0-9]*")
   AVax=regex.search(pacientvalues[0])
   AVOSax=re.sub("2.RO.*OS.*?ax[;\. 0-9]*?","",AVax[0])
   regex=re.compile("[\+\-0-9]+")
   if regex.search(AVOSax)==None:
       AVOSax="None"
   STRING=STRING+AVOSax+" "

   #3.PIO OD
   regex=re.compile("3.PIO.*OD=[;\.\+\- 0-9]*")
   AVfc=regex.search(pacientvalues[0])
   AVODfc=re.sub("3.PIO.*?OD=[;\. 0-9]*?","",AVfc[0])
   regex=re.compile("[\+\-0-9]+")
   if regex.search(AVODfc)==None:
       AVODfc="None"
   STRING=STRING+AVODfc+" "

   #3.PIO OS
   regex=re.compile("3.PIO.*?OS=[;\. 0-9]*")
   AVfc=regex.search(pacientvalues[0])
   AVOSfc=re.sub("3.PIO.*?OS=[;\. 0-9]*?","",AVfc[0])
   regex=re.compile("[\+\-0-9]+")
   if regex.search(AVOSfc)==None:
       AVOSfc="None"
   STRING=STRING+AVOSfc+" "


   #4.FO OD
   regex=re.compile("4.FO(?s).*OD:[;\.\+\- 0-9]*")
   AVfc=regex.search(pacientvalues[0])
   AVODfc=re.sub("4.FO(?s).*?OD:[;\. 0-9]*?","",AVfc[0])
   regex=re.compile("[\+\-0-9]+")
   if regex.search(AVODfc)==None:
       AVODfc="None"
   STRING=STRING+AVODfc+" "

   #4.FO OS
   regex=re.compile("4.FO(?s).*?OS:[;\. 0-9]*")
   AVfc=regex.search(pacientvalues[0])
   AVOSfc=re.sub("4.FO(?s).*?OS:[;\. 0-9]*?","",AVfc[0])
   regex=re.compile("[\+\-0-9]+")
   if regex.search(AVOSfc)==None:
       AVOSfc="None"
   STRING=STRING+AVOSfc+" "


################################################## NORMAL FROM HERE


   #remove space between a + - and a number    
   STRING=re.sub("\-( )+","-",STRING)
   STRING=re.sub("\+( )+ ","+",STRING)
   STRING=re.sub("(\-\+)","-+ ",STRING)
   STRING=re.sub("(\+\-)","+- ",STRING)

   #treatment
   regex = re.compile('TRATAMENT:(?s).*')
   treatment = regex.search(text)
   treatment = treatment[0].replace('TRATAMENT:',"")
   STRING=STRING+treatment
   STRING=STRING+DP
   regex=re.compile("( )+")
   STRING=STRING.replace('\n',' ').replace('\t', ' ').replace(';','')
   STRING=re.sub(regex," ",STRING)
   print (STRING)

f=open(input("file PATH: ") ,'r')
text=f.read()
valuesHextractor(text)  
f.close
```

> The other code I'm running

```
f=open("filenames.txt")
for filename in f:
    filename = filename.strip("\n")
    file=open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/toate/"+filename)
    text=file.read()
    valuesHextractor(text)
    file.close()
f.close()
```

The files are **.doc** - **Microsoft Word 2003**.

Opening one of the files with Notepad and trying to *`Save as`* it shows me their encoding is **ANSI**.

> Getting the following error:

```
== RESTART: C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/go.py ==
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/go.py", line 4, in <module>
    text=file.read()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1070: character maps to <undefined>
>>>
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
f=open("filenames.txt")
for filename in f:
    filename = filename.strip("\n")
    file=open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/toate/"+filename, encoding="mbcs") # <-----
    text=file.read()
    valuesHextractor(text)
    file.close()
f.close()
```

Ansi encoding is equal to mbcs according to this [python doc](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html). then opening the file with `encoding="mbcs"` should solve the issue.

**Update**: the error "UnicodeDecodeError" already implies that python already tried to decode it with 'utf-8' but it failed. Therefore, using 'utf-8' is not an option.

Comment: can you post the complete traceback?

Comment: That is very weird. I tried your code on my laptop. It works fine. Your error message is saying that the function "valuesHextractor" doesn't exist. But it does according to your code. The code you posted was it the entire file or just a snippet of it?

Comment: Umm, did you do `import valuesHextractor` in your `go.py`? Can I see your `go.py`? It seems you didn't import the functions. You forgot to mention they're in different files in your question.

Answer (score 10):

Open the file with "utf8" encoding.

```
f = open("filenames.txt", encoding="utf8")
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just add the following line in the top of your python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

OR

Read the file as a binary file and it should work.
Replace the this line

```
f=open(input("file PATH: ") ,'r')
```

with

```
f=open(input("file PATH: ") ,'rb')
```